# How do I reset NSSplitView views

Tags: macos, nswindow, nssplitview

This is a little hard to explain, but I will try my best.

This is how I setup my `NSSplitView` inside my mainWindow.

```
[self.splitView.subviews[0] addSubview:view0];
[self.splitView.subviews[1] addSubview:view1];
[self.splitView.subviews[2] addSubview:view2];
```

However, if I close the mainWindow and reopen it the views do not "reset" so to speak. It still has previous information for a little while until my app retrieves new information. Is there an elegant way to reset NSSplitView views? Thank you for any tips you might have.

Edit: I tried releasing my MainWindow, but if I do that I can't reopen the the window.

Comment: can you show where you set up your NSSplitView? Also, do those subviews all descend from the same base class, or only from NSView?

Comment: "I tried releasing my MainWindow, but if I do that I can't reopen the the window." So it is not released right? Maybe it should, and you should create a new window from the menu.

Comment: You can use the methods and properties of `NSSplitView` to reset the dividers.